# How to use TabBar in UiBinder in GWT or GWTP?

Tags: gwt, tabbar, tabpanel, gwtp

I am using GWTP, there is no such `RootLayoutPanel`, so it's quite difficult to use `TabLayoutPanel` or I don't know how to use it properly.

I want to change to use something simpler like `TabBar`; however, I can't find a method on how to use `TabBar` in `UiBinder`.

I need a simple Tab with a Tab header & a HTML for each tab. I tried `TabPanel` before and it worked fine, but `TabPanel` only supports Quirks mode & it's not good.

Here is the `TabBar` code I tried:

```xml
<g:TabBar>
    <g:tab>
          <g:header>Welcome2 dfddf f dfdf dfdf</g:header>
          <g:HTMLPanel>Hello tab 2<br />Good bye!2</g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:tab>
</g:TabBar>
```

After running it showed error:

```
Found unexpected child element: <g:tab>
```

How can I use the `TabBar` properly in `UiBinder`? If possible, can you provide a very simple example?

Comment: Why is there no `RootLayoutPanel` in GWTP ? See [here](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Layout-Panels) for more details.

Comment: Hi Umit, can u tell me how to use RootLayoutPanel in UiBinder in GwtP?

Comment: Besides, i don't want TabLayoutPanel in my top-level presenter. I want TabLayoutPanel in a normal presenter.

Comment: `LayoutPanels` have to be used with `RootLayoutPanel` to work properly. So you must place your `TabLayoutPanel` in another `LayoutPanel` and there should be an unbroken chain up to the `RootLayoutPanel`. You should use a normal `LayoutPanel` or a `DockLayoutPanel` for your `RootPresenter`.

Comment: Excuse me, whereas I consider this question not answered, I ask myself: where you able to solve it? I have the exact same problem. If I just define the tabbar in uibinder and then I add the tabs via code, it works, but I don't know how to add tabs directly inside uibinder. Someone could answer?